# How to capture Output of SQL queries and

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I have a Database and i want to execute few queries on it, and the results of the queries i.e. message, has to be comapared in my code if it is expected or not.
Please let me know how to capture the output of the SQL queries in any variable that can be used later in code for comparision.

Comment: Maybe this will help you .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552995/store-query-result-in-variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Method :

- Create a Table with the Same structure as of your Procedure output
- Insert the Result of the SP Execution to the Table
- Compare your Query result with the Table

Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uSp_Temp
AS
SELECT
    GETDATE() "MyDate"

DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    MyDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @T
EXEC uSp_Temp

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Temp tables or temp variable to save the result set of a query.

Below is the sample for temp table

```
create table #temp (id int)

insert into #temp 
select 1 as id

select * from #temp
```

Below is sample for Temp variable

```
declare  @temp table (id int)

insert into @temp 
select 1 as id

select * from @temp
```